# How to show holiday message on holiday date in ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

Currently, I am using ngx-bootstrap datepicker for appointment scheduling. I disable the weekend days as well as holiday date but the requirement is when we hover the mouse on holiday date it should be displayed holiday message in a tooltip.
[image]

This is my ngx-bootstrap datepicker. whenever I hover mouse on 13 or 15 august it should be displayed a proper message in a tooltip.
So Is there any solution is available for my question.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need something similar with the same control

Answer (score 1):

[image]

** Warning this answer requires further work/effort and is intended to suggest an approach.

Whilst this isn't THE answer as such it might set you off on a path of thought.

It's a bit "dirty" and there must be a better way?

I can't find anything in the API for datepicker for days mouseover events but you could try something like this.

Handle the onshown event and add your own mouseover event. Detect the disabled class on the span tag within td and add a title attribute.

HTML

```
<input bsDatepicker  (onShown)="onShown()" [daysDisabled]="[6,0]"/>
```

TypeScript

```
onShown(): void {
    const el = document.body.querySelector('.bs-datepicker-body table tbody');

    if (null !== el) {
      el.addEventListener('mouseover', this.onClick.bind(this));
    }
  }


.
.
.
onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'SPAN' && event.target.getAttribute('class') === 'disabled') {
      event.target.setAttribute('title', 'Disabled because it\'s a holiday');
    }
.
.
.
```

### 26/07/2019 Edit

Occurred to me on the way home last night that this is nasty hack. A slight *improvement* on this hack would be to avoid adding the mouseover event which will cause a lot of events.

My other solution would be to detect when the calendar is created `(onShown)` and then to loop over the  elements and add the tooltip on the fly to the disabled  elements. This is probably a better solution that doesn't require mouseover events.